# Silex, Symfony2 FormServiceProvider - SLOW

Tags: forms, performance, symfony, service, silex

time by time i'm trying to use Symfony FormServiceProvider and always have issues with speed witch actually stops me from going forward.

1.1 simple twig form - Execution Time: **0.28957605361938**

```
$app->match('/test2', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('form.html');
});
```

1.2 registering providers FormServiceProvider, TranslationServiceProvider - Execution Time: **0.36547303199768**

2.1 registering providers FormServiceProvider, TranslationServiceProvider and constructing form  - Execution Time: **1.0038349628448**

```
$app->match('/test1', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
$choices = array('1'=>'Mr.', '2'=>'Miss', '3'=>'Mrs.');
$data = array(
    'name' => 'my firstName',
    'email' => 'my lastName',
);

$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', $data)
    ->add('name')
    ->add('title', 'choice', array('choices'=>$choices))
    ->add('email')
    ->add('gender', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(1 => 'male', 2 => 'female'),
        'expanded' => true,
    ))
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array('form' => $form->createView()));
});
```

woooow!!!  1 sec !!! 3-4 TIMES SLOWER !!!
does it suppose to be so slow - or i'm doing something wrong ?
tests done on my osx virtualbox dev env 1024mb of ram, 2 cpu

Comment: Did you manage to have any luck with this? I'm experiencing similar speed issue with the FormServiceProvider

Comment: I found enabling twig caching speeds things up dramatically

Comment: i did not found any solution (tried twig caching too)